# IIB Message flow using HTTP input->compute->HTTP reply nodes

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

HTTP Rest Request reached HTTP Input node and processed in computenode. It then failed in HTTP Reply node with the below error:

**catch exception and rethrowing errr:Handle re used after re ply sent EVHT replyidentifier **

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter [Configuring message flows to process timeouts](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=flows-configuring-message-process-timeouts) explains timeout handling.

Specifically for your problem, you can use the [CHANGEIDENTIFIERTIMEOUT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=functions-changeidentifiertimeout-function) function like this:

```
DECLARE replyIdentifier BLOB InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestIdentifier;
IF replyIdentifier IS NOT NULL AND NOT CHANGEIDENTIFIERTIMEOUT(replyIdentifier, 1) THEN
    -- Do not propagate to the Reply node
    RETURN FALSE;
ELSE
    -- Flow did not timeout, so we can send the reply
    RETURN TRUE;
END IF;
```

Comment: thanks for the response i tried with the above code in the MQMD node and Request compute node but still facing the same issue. Here I am sharing my message flow can you please help me that where should i write this code exactly?



 
http input-->MQMD node-->Log-->Request Node-->Log-->HTTP Reply Node